# Converting formula to ARRAYFORMULA issues with SUM and INDEX

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a scoring spreadsheet for a competition I'm working on.  Competitors' place/rank are converted into points towards the overall series based on a chart of corresponding values.  For ties, the sum of the points covered by all of the tied places are split evenly among the tied competitors (i.e. 2-way tie for 3rd; if 3rd usually gets 10 points and 4th usually gets 8, these competitors will receive (10+8)/2 (2 being the # of tied competitors), so they each receive 9 points).
I have a formula which does this exact calculation:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK($A4:$A),,SUM(INDEX(SeriesPoints, E4:E):INDEX(SeriesPoints, MIN(E4:E + COUNTIF(E$4:E, E4:E) - 1, ROWS(SeriesPoints)))) / COUNTIF(E$4:E, E4:E), 0))
```

Where 'SeriesPoints' is a 2 column array; column 1 is the places/ranks (1:125) and column 2 is their corresponding point values.  Column 'E' is the competitors' rank from the competition.

I have been unable to convert this formula to an ARRAYFORMULA() so I can avoid dragging it down the entire sheet (possibly up to 1000+ competitors over the series).
I'm mildly proficient with MMULT(), so I understood that would be a good approach for switching out SUM(), however, I haven't been able to create a matrix of the values to be summed.
INDEX():INDEX() doesn't work with ARRAYFORMULA() so I've tried switching to VLOOKUP().  With VLOOKUP() I've been able to produce the start and end values of the range of values for a tie, but not the full list.  For example, if there is a 3-way tie for 4th, I can produce the respective points for 4th and 6th (the bounds of the tie).
In an attempt to list out even just the numbers from 4:6, I've hit a wall converting what would be a simple ROW() or SEQUENCE() formula to a matrix/array.

The following formula produces an array of the upper and lower bounds of ties or the single place should there be no tie, although the single place gets repeated.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(E$4:E,E4:E)=1,E4:E,{E4:E,E4:E+COUNTIF(E$4:E,E4:E)-1}))
```

I'm assuming if I can get VLOOKUP({#:#}) to fill properly, I'll be where I need to be.
From here, I feel confident in my abilities to wrap a VLOOKUP() for the actual point values, an MMULT() to sum across these rows for the total, then a simple division to produce the correct point value.

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lpNewR3p4i7ZHmlFGLlG1tLuxgO-6onSeH8mWTeclBw/edit?usp=sharing
Currently, my workspace is off to the right.  The original formula is in F4 and my test codes are working on column G instead of E.

So for sample placements of 1,1,3,3,3,6,7,8 and sample points values of 1000, 850,738,663,633,603,573,550 I expect the output to be 925 for the two 1st place tied competitors, 678 for the tied 3rd places, 603 for 6th, 573 for 7th, and 550 for 8th.

I'd appreciate any and all help!

Comment: not sure whats going on in your half-empty sheet... can you add example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: @player0 Desired output has been added and some of the empty columns have been removed.
This sheet was a duplication of the original to hide some of the personal data, sorry it's a little messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4:G, QUERY({INDIRECT("G4:G"&counta(A4:A)+3), 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A4:A))), SeriesPoints, 2, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0))/
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4:G, QUERY(G4:G, 
 "select G,count(G) where G is not NULL group by G label count(G)''", 0), 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It doesn't appear that this works if the competitors are not sorted by place/rank.  Is there a fix to the formula that will fix this, I'd prefer not to reformat how the competitors are added to the sheet.

Comment: @JoshLowy `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4:G, QUERY({SORT(INDIRECT("G4:G"&counta(A4:A)+3)), VLOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A4:A))), SeriesPoints, 2, 0)}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0))/ IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4:G, QUERY(SORT(G4:G), "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not NULL group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0))))`

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks so much @player0 !!